# MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 1343667 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, protocolexception

I'm getting `java.net.ProtocolException` for some of the videos. This is how passing the URL to `videoview`. Did anyone face this before?

```
videoview.setVideoURI(videourl);
```

Comment: did you find the solution..?

Comment: @V.Y. Check the answer below

Answer (score -1):

After several rounds of debugging, I figured out it is due to the unsupported video format. Android default Mediaplayer or Videoview doesn't support all formats, for eg: MOV.

By using the [exoplayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer) you can overcome this issue.
Pls chk the supported formats [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats).

```
 private void initializePlayer(String downloadedFile) {

    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
    player.addListener(eventListener);

    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this, "Player"));

    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();


    MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(streamurl,
            dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);


    player.prepare(videoSource, false, false);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    videoview.setShutterBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    videoview.setPlayer(player);
    videoview.requestFocus();
}


@Override
public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isPlaying) {
    Log.d(TAG,"videoplaying onLoadingChanged::"+isPlaying);
}

@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING){
      //show progressbar
    } else {
        //dismiss progressbar
    }
}

}
```